# How to translate this query by cake php and how to call count?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm trying to convert this query to CakePHP `find()`. But I fail, I cannot get to use count:

```
SELECT *, COUNT( room_type_id ) >=3 AS count
FROM rooms
GROUP BY room_type_id;
```

In CakePHP find() :

```
$rooms = $this->Room->find('all',array(
  'fields' => array('Room.*', 'RoomType.*', 'count(Room.room_type_id) >= 3 AS count_room')),
  'conditions' => array("NOT" => array('Room.id' => $rNo)),
  'group' => array('Room.room_type_id'),
));
```

How to get count by cakephp

I use this count in the following :

```
foreach($rooms as $room){
  echo "ROOM COUNT : ".$room['count'];
}
```

but it's not OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two *main* ways of doing that.

If you are only interested in the `count` value, you should definitely use the `'count'` option of CakePHP `AppModel::find()` method:

```
$this->Room->find('count', array(
  'conditions' => array('Room.room_type_id >=' => 3, ...),
  'recursive' => 0, // Optional, in case you need to speed up things a bit
));
```

This way, the `find` method does return the count value directly and `GROUP BY` does not make sense.

But if you want to retrieve every column as well, you can use a 'regular' find query like this:

```
$this->Room->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array('Room.room_type_id >=' => 3, ...),
  'group' => 'Room.room_type_id',
  'fields' => array('Room.*', 'count(Room.room_type_id) as room_count'),
  'recursive' => 0, // Optional, in case you need to speed up things a bit
));
```

Where `find()` would return an array like:

```
[0] =>
  [Room] => 
    [room_type_id] => 3
    [0] =>
      [room_count] => 2,
...
```

I don't remember how exactly CakePHP returns the array, but you can use `debug()` to inspect it and know how to retrieve it (e.g. `$rooms[0]['Room'][0]['room_count']`).

Last note: retrieving every column value and including a `GROUP BY` clause does not make much sense unless you use a [SQL aggregate function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp) for each column (or unless you really know what you're doing).

Comment: Yes, I wanna to retrieve every column but this column is total count of room type is greater than 3. e.g I want to reserve 3 room of same type from hotel. So I get data that have 3 rooms of same room type. That's why how to get count of each room_type is greater than 3.

Comment: I have edited the answer to give you more details about how retrieve the count value in case you are not using the `'count'` option.

Comment: OK, I know about that but i don't know how to get room_count by php code.e.g. if wanna get room_type_id... $room['Room']['room_type_id'] but i get room_count by $room['room_count']... is not OK. Please explain me how to get room_count. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `find( 'count' )` function:

```
$this->Room->find( 
    'count',
    array(
        'conditions' => array( 'room_type_id >= 3' ),
        'group'      => 'room_type_id'
    )
);
```

Comment: How to get this count? Please answer me.

Comment: No, not like this. I wanna get a total count of room_type_id that total count is greater than 3. Not id is greater than 3.